# DBus over Network (TCP)

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, dbus

I'm trying to communicate with a remote DBus (i.e. IP 10.100.20.101) from a host (i.e. IP 10.100.20.102) - X86_64 platform to ARM development board.

I've tried the solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158684/connecting-to-dbus-over-tcp) but it caused my system to lock after rebooting, and I needed to undo all changes. Tried Gabriel too, but it is not updated since 2007 and it doesn't work as expected anymore.

What I did in remote side was copy session.conf and add:

```
<listen>tcp:host=localhost,bind=*,port=55560,family=ipv4</listen>

<auth>ANONYMOUS</auth>

<allow_anonymous/>
```

After that, launched:

```
dbus-launch --config-file=mynewsession.conf
```

With output:

```
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=tcp:host=10.100.20.101,port=55560,family=ipv4,guid=4f69480729f1879d20fec07c563b9f5c
```

On the host side:

```
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=tcp:host=10.100.20.101,port=55560,family=ipv4
```

But when I execute qdbus to watch what is going on remote DBus, the output is:

```
Could not connect to D-Bus server: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
```

Someone can tell me a way to do DBus communication over TCP correctly?

Comment: Have you tried using Wireshark to check what happens during the connection?

Comment: Did you remember to disable apparmor?

Comment: I will try to use Wireshark to see what is happening @grawity.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I've added the tag for disabling apparmor on session.conf and system.conf (both sides of communication) but no changes at all.

Comment: Have you seen [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158684/connecting-to-dbus-over-tcp) ?

Comment: @Toni & @user41669 : You need to comment upon the answers in my above link so we can know more about your problem(s). For example (1) putting the `<listen>` tag first in session.conf, and (2) using `bind=0.0.0.0` instead of `bind=*`. Adding your session.conf and system.conf files to the post will also be helpful.